# Loading image dynamically from Applet

Tags: java, image, applet, appletviewer

I have the following Applet code to load an image.

```
public void init(){
    str = "Hi, Welcome!";

    sharedImage = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "/Users/Me/ScreenShare/testImage.png");
}
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    g.drawString(str, 50, 50);
    g.drawImage(sharedImage, 100, 100, this);
}
```

But, I want to load this dynamically now, because the image from this path will be changing to new image every 5 seconds. How to refresh the image in Applet by itself if I do not use any html page to run the applet?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Most image loading methods in the JSE will cache images for efficiency.  The way around it is ..not to use them, but instead to use lower level methods that will not cause the image to be cached.  To do that:

- Load the `byte[]` of the current image.
- Use the byte array to form a [`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#ByteArrayInputStream%28byte%5b%5d%29).
- Load the byte array input stream using [`ImageIO.read(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29).

Comment: Could you explain a bit more with the some samples please?

Comment: Could you try something first ..or pay me consultancy fees?

Comment: Sorry to disturb you :) . I tried already with timer and calling repaint, so that i thought it can update the image periodically on the Applet. But, it is calling the repaint and drawImage function, but Applet not updating the image at run time. Here is the code: timer = new Timer(); timer = new Timer(true); 
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() { public void run() {
repaint(); } }, delay, period);

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example) as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21600141/edit).  But some advice, it is impractical (for security reasons) to make an applet based MCTaRE that loads images.  So sort this out in a normal `JFrame` or `JOptionPane` based GUI with no security manager first.